# Connecting to MongoDB from homestead: Operation not permitted

Tags: mongodb, laravel-6, homestead

I'm trying to connect to

```
mongodb+srv://USER:PASSWORD@CLUSTER.drknv.mongodb.net/qa?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

from Laravel 6 in Homestead but I get

```
Failed to look up SRV record Operation not permitted
```

Though I can connect to it using the same DSN from Compass. Please note that username, password and cluster name don't contain any special characters. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: "Failed to look up SRV record" is a DNS failure, it hasn't even attempted to connect to the mongodb server at that point.

Comment: perhaps take a look at https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1879#issuecomment-590749800